# DDL Trigger For Logon Insert data to a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl-trigger

I have a below DDL Trigger on my server

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DDLForLogin] ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @data XML
    SET @data = EVENTDATA()

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.Databases WHERE NAME = 'DatabaseMaintenance') Begin
        INSERT INTO DatabaseMaintenance.dbo.MyTable (UserName, HostName, ApplicationName, EventDataValue)
        VALUES (CURRENT_USER, HOST_Name(), APP_NAME(),@Data)
    END  
END;
```

a login as `Windows Authentication` insert one row on MyTable but a login as `SQL Server Authentication` raised below error :

```
Logon failed for login 'xxx' due to trigger execution.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Changed language setting to us_english. (Microsofr SQL Server, Error: 17892)
```

**EDIT**

I `GRANT INSERT` on my table to `PUBLIC`.

but no change on raised error.

**EDIT2**

I change my trigger and add `With Execute AS 'sa'` on the trigger

but no change on raised error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must change trigger to below code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DDLForLogin] ON ALL SERVER
WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
FOR LOGON 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @data XML
    SET @data = EVENTDATA()

    DECLARE @IsPooled int
    SET @IsPooled = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/IsPooled)[1]', 'int')

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.Databases WHERE NAME = 'DatabaseMaintenance')AND (@IsPooled=0) Begin
        insert into DatabaseMaintenance.dbo.Login (UserName, HostName, ApplicationName, EventDataValue)
        values (ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), HOST_Name(), APP_NAME(),@Data)
    END
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an appropriate [`EXECUTE AS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) clause to your [trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) - the default is `CALLER`, so unless *that* user has permissions to insert into your audit table<sup>1</sup>, the trigger will fail.

Also, then use [`ORIGINAL_LOGIN()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189492.aspx) in the trigger to get the correct login information

<sup>1</sup> Which you normally don't want - because otherwise every user can forge entries alleging that other users have logged in.